# Comparing Arrays using .map (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

In my project, I have 2 arrays being read from Firestore.

**courseList** - A list of courses of which a user is enrolled in

**courses** - A list of all of the courses available in the project

I would like to compare these using a .map so that in my course portal, only the courses of which the user is enrolled in is rendered.

Here is what the arrays look like:

**courseList:**

[image]

**courses**

[image]

I know the arrays  work, however, the .map doesn't seem to be working!

Here's my code:

```
const {courses} = this.state
const {courseList} = this.state

{
                

                  courses.length && courses.map (course => {
                    
                         if (course.courseUrl === courseList.CourseCode) {

                              return (
                                 <div className = "CourseTile" key = {course.courseName}>

                                   <div className = "CourseTitle">
                                        <h1> {course.courseName}</h1>
                                  </div>

                                  <div className = "CourseDescription">
                                        <p> {course.courseSummary}</p>
                                  </div>

                                  <Link to={`/course/${course.courseUrl}/courseinformation`}> <button className = "LetsGoButton"> Take course</button> </Link>

                                </div>
                              )
                        }

                          else return null;
                
                  }
                )
                

}
```

If I replace

```
if (course.courseUrl === courseList.CourseCode)
```

with

```
if (course.courseUrl === "websitedesign")
```

It renders the website design course only, So I believe there's something wrong with this line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of course.courseUrl.I think you need to map with course list value and check with course code

Comment: Did you check for `courseList` value?

Comment: @ZealousWeb the course.courseUrl is the equivalent of the CourseCode in courseList, I just don't have a specific CourseCode object in this array since it's the same as the url

Comment: @kunquan I did in the .map and it's undefined,  so that is deffo where my issue lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in where the problem lies:

`course.courseUrl === courseList.CourseCode`

In this case `course` is a single item from a list, with a property `courseUrl`. That's fine. But `courseList` is an array of items, **each of which** has a `CourseCode` property. The Array itself does not (although, interestingly, it could).

It seems like what you are trying to do is pull the full course data (from courses) but filtered to only the ones the user has. In this case, you have to loop through one list, looking through the other list for each item. What you want is `filter` (or, more powerfully, `reduce`) but probably not `map`.

`const filteredCourses = availableCourses.filter( availableCourse => studentsCourses.some( studentsCourse => studentsCourse.id === availableCourse.id ) );`

You'll notice I renamed the variables to make it clear which of the two lists is being used at each part.

The outer function `filter` will return a new array containing only those items that return 'true' in the callback function.

The inner callback function `some` loops through another array (the student's enrolled courses) and returns true if it finds *any* that match the given condition.

So in English, "Filter this list of all the courses, giving me back only the courses that have a matching ID in the list of the student's enrolled courses."

Answer (score 0):

> `if (course.courseUrl === courseList.CourseCode)`

You can filter the `courses` array by checking if each `course` is included in the `courseList` array, matching an URL to a `courseList` element's `CourseCode` property. `array.prototype.some` is used to iterate  the course list and check that *at least* one `courseList` item matches. Once filtered you can map the filtered result as per normal.

```
const {courses} = this.state;
const {courseList} = this.state;

...

{courses
  .filter(({ courseUrl }) => 
    courseList.some(({ CourseCode }) => CourseCode === courseUrl)
  )
  .map((course) => {
    return (
      <div className="CourseTile" key={course.courseName}>
        <div className="CourseTitle">
          <h1> {course.courseName}</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="CourseDescription">
          <p> {course.courseSummary}</p>
        </div>

        <Link to={`/course/${course.courseUrl}/courseinformation`}>
          {" "}
          <button className="LetsGoButton"> Take course</button>{" "}
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  })}
```